# Cordova CLI: Ant build not installing

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ant, cordova-cli

I'm trying to install `Cordova CLI Interface`. I need to install `Ant Build` but every time I add platorm `cordova platfrom add android`, gradle build gets installed.

Anybody knows why gradle is been installed? I'm following these steps after installing the node.js.

1. `npm install -g cordova@3.6`
2. `cordova create <dir_name> com.blah <app_name>`
3. `cordova plaform add android`

Environment variables and paths are all set, but still Ant is not being installed.

I'm following this [link](http://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/create-cordova-project.html) for installation, this worked when I'm using Win 7, but now I switched to Win 8 64 bit.

Comment: What link? Also, you can always get Apache Ant [from the official site](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to attach the link, you can see it now. @Huey